# Can I constraint an AutoIncremented column not to accept values from outside?

Tags: sql, mysql, auto-increment

I have an AutoIncremented column (ID), and I want to have a constraint that only the database ever fills in this column. Is there a constraint for that?

Comment: can you please describe "Outside"

Comment: I'd like any INSERT into that table with bad data to fail.

Comment: I always thought that when you define a column as auto increment, and attempt to set the column with insert will fail..   which is why bulk import scripts disable that before setting all that data..  I could be wrong though.  I assume you tried to do this and it worked?  What sql flavor?

Comment: Yeap, I tried and it works, mysql.

Comment: " database ever fills in this column" I think here is little bit confusion, do u want to set a constraint on an autoincremented column so that no one can insert/update the ID value in any way.

Comment: Exactly that - I want only the database to ever create the ID, and nothing to ever change it.

Comment: I too had a similar question regarding the permission for making changes only thru stored procedure 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901466/how-should-i-work-in-this-scenario-should-i-use-trigger-or-leave-on-user-to-man
Check this how to set permissions on database. 
http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a declarative constraint that can do this.

You can do it using a trigger, for example:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER ForceId BEFORE INSERT ON MyTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.id = DEFAULT;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

I just tested this on MySQL 5.1.41 and it seems to work.  If I specify a value for `id` in my `INSERT` statement, it ignores my value and generates a new surrogate key value.

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (id, name) VALUES (DEFAULT, 'Bill');
INSERT INTO MyTable (id, name) VALUES (123, 'John');
SELECT * FROM MyTable;
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | bill  |
|  2 | john  |
+----+-------+
```